# iOS Causing Network-Wide Disruption

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone

So, interesting problem, whenever I plug my iPhone 6 Plus into charge, I get massive disruption across my whole network, wired and wireless. Once it starts, the only solution is to either disable the phone's WiFi or reboot the device. The image below shows a PingPlotter graph of the problem in action.

[image: graph]

Has anoyone seen this sort of behavior before? If so, any recommendation on troubleshooting?

Comment: Try resetting the network settings in your iPhone. Re-join the Wi-Fi to see if the problem happens again.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have iCloud backup turned on the device? I've experienced this before when I had the service turned on (have since turned it off).

Comment: +1 This is probably the culprit. iCloud is likely set to sync when charging and connected to WiFi.

Comment: OK, so after a bit of trial and error, this is definitely the culprit.  What I am not understanding is that, of the 6 iOS devices on the network, why would the one device be the single offender?